# JTable renderer don't change background

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am using this following daughter class of `JTable`, and don't manage to change any background color cell :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public abstract class GenericConfigurationTable  extends JTable {
    private EditableCellRenderer t = new EditableCellRenderer();
    private DefaultCellRenderer d = new DefaultCellRenderer();
    protected boolean[] editable;

    public GenericConfigurationTable(AbstractTableModel m) {
        this();
        this.setModel(m);
    }

    public GenericConfigurationTable() {
        this.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
        this.setBackground(ViewsPreferences.P_TABLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.setShowGrid(false);
        this.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(this.getPreferredSize());
    }

    protected void setRenderers() {
        TableColumnModel u = this.getColumnModel();

        for(int i = 0; i < this.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            if(editable[i])
                u.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(t);
            else
                u.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(d);
        }
    }

    public class EditableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
        public EditableCellRenderer() {
            this.setFont(ViewsPreferences.SU_EDITABLE_CELL_FONT);
            this.setForeground(ViewsPreferences.SU_EDITABLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR);
            this.setBackground(ViewsPreferences.SU_EDITABLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
            setBorder(null);
            this.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if(value != null)
                setText(value.toString());
            else
                setText("");

            return this;
        }
    }

    public class DefaultCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
        public DefaultCellRenderer() {
            this.setFont(ViewsPreferences.SU_CELL_FONT);
            this.setForeground(ViewsPreferences.SU_CELL_FOREGROUND_COLOR);
            this.setBackground(ViewsPreferences.SU_CELL_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
            setBorder(null);
            this.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if(value != null)
                setText(value.toString());
            else
                setText("");
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

So I thought it was linked with the fact I try to render any type in two renderers so I tried setting the renderer with `table.setDefaultRenderer(Type.class, myRenderer)` but nothing changed too.

Here is a part of the table model used :

```
public class T extends AbstractTableModel {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        private final Class[] columns_class = { String.class, String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, String.class, Double.class}; 
        private final String[] columns_names = { "Type", "Champs", "HM", "A", "V", "Fc" };
        private final String[] row_labels = {"J1", "J2", "J3", "J4", "J5", "J7", "J8", "J9", "J10", "J11", "J100", " ", " ", "JS", "JC"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JLabel is transparent by default so the background will never be painted.

To paint the background of the label you need to make the label opaque. In your constructor of the renderer you need to add:

```
this.setOpaque( true );
```

Comment: Thank you camickr, I was searching way too far away ^^